# What does 「Nounを笑え」 phrase mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, usage, phrases, song-lyrics

> Oh! KAREN 浜辺の濡れた砂の上で
> 抱きあう幻を笑え

It's from a song 「恋するカレン」by 大滝詠一. Lyrics [here](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a001134/l0118f0.html).

Based on my understanding, here's my translation:
*Oh! KAREN I laugh at my dream of embracing you in my arms on wet sand on the beach*

Would "laugh at"  something be the appropriate or close enough meaning for Nounを笑え. I say "laugh at" because searching for「〜を笑え」showed up this sentence in the search results (as title of one of the youtube videos)

> Laugh at life～人生を笑え～

Video with that title [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoCj5gNquL8).

宜しくおねがいします

Answer (score 2, accepted):

笑え is the *imperative* form of 笑う, so literally, it's not "I laugh at my dream" but "Laugh at this dream I had (until now)!". It doesn't make much sense for him to tell Karen to laugh at himself in this context, so I think he's saying this to no one in particular (or, to the listeners of this song). He's describing how silly and laughable his 幻 was.

Also note that ～**を**笑う is somewhat special. 笑う is usually an intransitive verb (～**に**笑う / ～**で**笑う). The transitive usage of 笑う (～**を**笑う) has a scornful/derogatory overtone. You may want to pick a more negative word to translate this ～を笑え.

- [Why isn't 笑う usually used with に particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59047/5010)

  > When used as a transitive verb, 笑う means "laugh at~~" in the sense of "ridicule" "deride" "sneer at~~" "make fun of~~".
- ["The eye (crust ?) laughs at the booger"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36517/5010)

By the way, 抱き**合う** is "to embrace *each other*".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! `Oh! KAREN laugh at my dream of 
embracing each other on the wet sand on the beach` sounds like he is telling KAREN to do it. Would `Oh! KAREN the dream I saw of us embracing each other on wet sand on the beach seems so silly/laughable now` be a better translation?

Comment: `By the way, 抱き合う is "to embrace each other".` good catch :)

Comment: @vadasambar "Please laugh at my dream, Karen" is a natural translation if we see only this part of the lyrics. However, from the entire lyrics, this guy is watching her from a remote place, and he is basically trying to laugh at Karen, not trying to be laughed at by Karen. But that's my personal impression.

Comment: @vadasambar `the dream I saw seems so silly` is a free translation but seems good to me.

Comment: so if we look at the two lines alone, the lyrics translate to `Please laugh at my dream, Karen` but if we take the context of the song into consideration, and it can or does mean He is trying to laugh at Karen. Would this not contradict the answer `It doesn't make much sense for him to tell Karen to laugh at himself in this context, so I think he's saying this to no one in particular (or, to the listeners of this song).` ? Thank you!